# Ansible hosts not working using specified inventory

Tags: ansible

I have two files

inventory.yaml:

```
servers:
  hosts:
    nas:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.27
    router:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.1
```

and playbook.yaml

```
- name: pylonl playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    -name: Ping all hosts
     ansible.builtin.ping:
```

running `ansible -i inventory.yaml all -m ping` works, but running `ansible -i inventory.yaml playbook.yaml` returns:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: playbook.yaml
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ansible-playbook` rather than `bin/ansible` "ad-hoc" to run plays.

`ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml playbook.yaml`